# spark streaming compare two batch and filter data

Tags: apache-spark, streaming

I want use spark streaming compare two batch and filter data

every 5s one batch,

first batch:

```
key     type
aaa     0
aaa     1
bbb     0
ccc     0
```

second batch:

```
key     type
aaa     1
bbb     1
ddd     0
```

when spark streaming Handle the second batch, compare with first batch, then filter result:

```
key     type
ccc     0
```

Two adjacent batches , The data(type is 0) for the last batch must be(type is 1) in the previous batch, and the current batch,like this:

```
key     type
aaa     0
aaa     1
```

then third batch:

```
key     type
ddd     1
eee     0
```

the filter result is null

How to use Spark Streaming to do this ?

Thanks

Comment: Can you paste the code snippet?

Comment: Sorry，no code snippet.I think the spark streaming windows function can do this.I am try now.

Comment: Yes you would be able to do that using spark streaming function I thought you have already done that and facing any issues

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I use variable to save my batch data,like this:

```
val preData = new java.util.ArrayList[String]
val currentData = new java.util.ArrayList[String]

def foreachRddFunc = (rdd:Rdd[String]) => {

rdd.collect().forecah(x => {
... ...
currentData.add(x)
... ...
})

//preData compare current data
... ... 

preData.addAll(currentData)

currentData.clear
}
```

do this operation must be on the driver .